# Sequences - Find the next term in the sequence

Tags: sequence, series, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to figure out the next term in the following sequence but I'm stumped.

```
1, 5, 2, 10, 3, 15, ....
```

Can someone explain the pattern and hence what the next term should be?

Comment: 4, 20, 5, 25 ...... the odd numbers are just plain increasing 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 - and the even numbers in between are 5 times the preceding odd number.....